# How does OpenStack determine "Available Instances", "Available vCPUs", and "Available RAM"?

Tags: openstack

I have a new OpenStack installation on a Server with 8 cores and 16GB of RAM.   How does OpenStack determine that I have 10 "Available Instances", 20 "Available vCPUs", and 51,200 MB of "Available RAM"?

[image: Horizon Dashboard]

Is this a configuration setting somewhere in my setup, or has it calculated it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is configuration. You can modify it in the Dashboard, when connected as an admin user, got to the "Admin" tab, "Projects" item, for each project, you can "Modify Quota". This is how it goes in my Openstack Folsom install.

Comment: Ahah! With the caveat that you should change to a different project before doing this.  If you attempt to change the project you're currently in, then it throws errors and wipes all the quotas in that project.  :-o

Answer (score 1):

OpenStack determines these values using the value of the in_use field in the row for the relevant project in the quota_usages table in the underlying MySQL database.